# MVC.NET Drag and Drop Toolbox to build layout page at runtime

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, drag-and-drop, toolbox

I'm trying to create a drag and drop style toolbox using MVC.NET, similar to Visual Studio for an application I'm developing. Basically the first part of the app allows the user to create a custom layout which will be used throughout the site.

I've tried a few different approaches to this but can't seem to hit one that works. My last attempt used the jQueryUI modal to allow the user to input the attributes of the item, say a div. This works and I can use AJAX to post the attribute values to my controller.

This is where I get stuck. I don't know what would be the best way to append the item to the layout page. I was toying around with Streamwriter but it was proving difficult to keep track of where on the page the item was placed.

I'm in the process of trying to do it via jQuery, but I'm just wondering if there is any options in the jQuery library or MVC.NET framework which I don't know about that might be useful.

Comment: Do you have options they can choose from for layout? Or are they actually tailoring HTML as they design?

Comment: I can have pre-made layouts for the user to choose but I also want to give them the option to tailor html as they design. I can already get them to drag an item from the toolbox to the viewport, this posts the id of the item to a controller and returns the item type (div, label etc.) upon the successful post a modal pops and allows the users to input the item attributes. On hitting the confirm button another post is done to a different controller which generates the markup. My problem is how to inject this to the layout page and maintain it as the user adds and configures more html.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [jQuery UI Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)?

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting?

Comment: Don't know who down voted it. I'm already using UI Draggable and Droppable. Please see comments above. The functionality I can't seem to get my head around is injecting the custom html to the layout page and maintaining that while the user edits and injects more html